Force do-release-upgrade not to fail
I'm trying to update an already EOL Ubuntu version (18.04) using the do-release-upgrade command. Prompts, screen and other update steps follow. No third-party repositories are enabled inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ or similar routes.
Everything goes smooth until the console shows this part:
Do you want to rewrite your 'sources.list' file anyway? If you choose 
'Yes' here it will update all 'bionic' to 'focal' entries. 
If you select 'No' the upgrade will cancel. 

Continue [yN] y

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Killed
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Killed
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Killed

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x 
/usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i', 
E:Sub-process returned an error code 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

First of all. Why is the tool killing the update? I already tried restricting the kill command because I doubt the developer's choice on killing the process. The server is a digitalocean droplet, so a network issue is basically bullshit.
The important part I think it's:
E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x 
/usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i', 
E:Sub-process returned an error code 

At first this error was popping up, which made me think this DigitalOcean crapware repository was causing issues:
Err:2 https://repos-droplet.digitalocean.com/apt/droplet-agent main InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 35696F43FC7DB4C2

But, even after disabling such repo the process still fails.
Is it better to do the old dist-upgrade/full-upgrade commands workflow? Or is there a way to force do-release-upgrade not to follow the developer's moronic choices? Anything that can make this work is welcome.
